# Python , XML AttributeError: 'NodeList' object has no attribute 'firstChild'

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

Hello I am having trouble with a xml file I am using. Now what happens is whenever i try to get the msg tag i get an error preventing me from accessing the data. Here is the code I am writing so far.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from datetime import datetime

def xml_data ():

  f = open('C:\opidea_2.xml', 'r')

  data = f.read()

  f.close()

  dom = minidom.parseString(data)

  ic = (dom.getElementsByTagName('logentry'))

  dom = None      
  content = ''  
  for num in ic:

    xmlDate = num.getElementsByTagName('date')[0].firstChild.nodeValue

    content += xmlDate + '\n '

    xmlMsg = num.getElementsByTagName('msg')


    if xmlMsg !='' and len(xmlMsg) > 0:
        xmlMsgc = xmlMsg[0].firstChild.nodeValue
        content += "   Comments: \n        " + str(xmlMsg) + '\n\n'

    else:
        xmlMsgc = "No comment made."

        content += xmlMsgc

  print content

if __name__ == "__main__":
xml_data ()
```

Here is part of the xml if it helps.

```
 <log>
 <logentry
  revision="33185">
 <author>glv</author>
 <date>2012-08-06T21:01:52.494219Z</date>
 <paths>

 <path
  kind="file"
  action="M">/branches/Patch_4_2_0_Branch/text.xml</path>   

 <path
  kind="dir"
  action="M">/branches/Patch_4_2_0_Branch</path>

</paths>
<msg>PATCH_BRANCH:N/A
 BUG_NUMBER:N/A
 FEATURE_AFFECTED:N/A
 OVERVIEW:N/A
  Adding the SVN log size requirement to the branch 
 </msg>
  </logentry>
    </log>
```

Now when i use `xmlMsg = num.getElementsByTagName('msg')[0].toxml()` I can get the code to work, I just have to do a lot of replacing and I rather not have to do that. Also I have date working using `xmlDate = num.getElementsByTagName('date')[0].firstChild.nodeValue`.

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong? Also here is the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\src\SVN_Email_copy.py", line 141, in <module>
    xml_data ()
  File "C:python\src\SVN_Email_copy.py", line 94, in xml_data
    xmlMsg = num.getElementsByTagName('msg').firstChild.nodeValue
AttributeError: 'NodeList' object has no attribute 'firstChild'
```

Comment: There should be indented better I believe. Sorry not very good with that posting it here.

Comment: You should code format everything that isn't text, including tracebacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest a different approach. Below is a program that does what you want (*I think...*). It uses the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead of minidom. This simplifies things quite a bit.

You have posted several related questions concerning parsing of an XML file using minidom. I really think you should look into ElementTree (and for even more advanced stuff, check out ElementTree's "superset", [lxml](http://lxml.de)). Both these APIs are much easier to work with than minidom.

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def xml_data():
    root = ET.parse("opidea_2.xml")
    logentries = root.findall("logentry")
    content = ""

    for logentry in logentries:
        date = logentry.find("date").text
        content += date + '\n '
        msg = logentry.find("msg")
        if msg is not None:
            content += "   Comments: \n        " + msg.text + '\n\n'
        else:
            content += "No comment made."

    print content

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xml_data()
```

Output when using your XML sample (you may want to work a bit more on the exact layout):

```
2012-08-06T21:01:52.494219Z
    Comments: 
        PATCH_BRANCH:N/A
 BUG_NUMBER:N/A
 FEATURE_AFFECTED:N/A
 OVERVIEW:N/A
  Adding the SVN log size requirement to the branch
```

Comment: Thank you. This definitly looks easier to deal with the minidom. will consider it. cause this is less lines of code to deal with thats for sure lol. And yes it does do what I want it to do.

Answer (score 3):

I was doing the code wrong it seems. Here is how i was able to solve it.

```
if len(xmlMsg) > 0 and xmlMsg[0].firstChild != None:

        xmlMsgc = xmlMsg[0].firstChild.nodeValue

        xmlMsgpbr = xmlMsgc.replace('\n', '       ')  

        xmlMsgf.append(xmlMsgpbr)        

    else:    

        xmlMsgf = "No comments made"
```

I never checked if first child had any value or not. That's what I was missing. the other answers helped well but this is how i was able to get it to work. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

```
myNodeList.item( 0)
```

maybe...
http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html

Comment: When I tried that on here below:
xmlMsg = num.getElementsByTagName('msg')[0].firstChild.item(0)

I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\CVS\CVS-Head\workspace\python_test_1\src\SVN_Email_copy.py", line 141, in <module>
    xml_data ()
  File "C:\CVS\CVS-Head\workspace\python_test_1\src\SVN_Email_copy.py", line 94, in xml_data
    xmlMsg = num.getElementsByTagName('msg')[0].firstChild.item(0)
AttributeError: Text instance has no attribute 'item'

Comment: hmmm i dunno It should be an attribute of XML NodeList  ...  so what happens if you just do firstChild ? not the nodevalue part?

Comment: xmlMsg = num.getElementsByTagName('msg')[0].firstChild

Well when i do it i do get the <DOM Text node "u'PATCH_BRAN'..."> but thats about it. Not something really read-able in it. I am not sure why the nodeValue isn't working with this.

Comment: I noticed something on a smaller xml log file it will work with the .firstChild.nodeValue , but for a longer file it does not. Now I edited the code and added a len checker to make sure that there is a comment but not sure if that will work. The error i got doesn't seem related to that type of an error.

Comment: I think it might be a null issue I may have to add more to my if statement. I may need to add a != and len(xmlMsg) >0 :

but that doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

use this... `print "%s" %(num.getElementsByTagName('date')[0].firstChild.data)`